# Rename file with the .bak extension

Tags: batch-file, window

I am trying to rename a file that has the .bak extension. But I won't know the test56.bak name since it changes all the time.

So lets say:

test56.bak

Rename to:

Upload.bak

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
rename F:\BackupRestore *.bak Upload.bak
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax you used is incorrect

> REN [drive:][path]SourceMask TargetMask

correct syntax:

```
rename F:\BackupRestore\*.bak Upload.bak
```

for multiple file

```
dir c:\bkp\ /A:-D /b | findstr.exe /n /R "*.bkp" > %temp%/file-count.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "%temp%/file-count.txt"') do set NUMBER-OF-FILES=%%A

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%number-of-files%) DO CALL rename %%A
:rename

FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "%temp%/file-count.txt" ^| findstr "%1:"') do ren %%B upload-%RANDOM%.bak
```

Comment: Thank you!! Will thumbs you up when it lets me.

Comment: your welcome mr hen If my post solved your problem please go ahead and accept

Comment: With the `*` wildcard (Match any characters) your command will fail raising `errorlevel` 1 and printing `A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found` message if present more  than right one `.bak` file!

Comment: @JosefZ if you see question he want change one file and i think bak file is single also possible some app not configure for rewrite bak file i change my answer for multiple file !

Comment: Your _think_ does not matter. The `rename F:\BackupRestore\*.bak Upload.bak` with `*` is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @JosefZ i think misunderstood my comment i tell you that is backup policy if they have infinite backup file and do not config rewrite last backup big problem happen that's not my think that's policy in all organization !